# In a GitLab runner SSH to local network that has IP as default Docker Bridge IP

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-networking, gitlab-runner

I have a GitLab Pipeline based on the python:3.10.11 image. The runner needs access to a local network that is on 172.17.0.0 via SSH/Paramiko. But it is unable to connect to the newtwork, when the runner pings an IP on the local network, it says Destination Host Unreachable. I imagine this is because the default Docker subnet is also 172.17.0.0. Is it possible to change the default Docker Bridge IP for a GitLab runner? Perhaps in the config.toml file?